# Print own message, if Python unable to parse xml data

Tags: python, xml, printf

Let us suppose. I have xml data, which is not well-formed. Can I print own message like:

> xml is not well performed

.

**python code**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse('data.xml').getroot()
# ParseError: mismatched tag: line 8, column 26
print('xml is not well performed')
```

Comment: You can wrap your `ET.parse` in a try-except block. If an exception is raised, print a message.

Comment: try:
except ParseError:

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
try:
    root = ET.parse('data.xml').getroot()
except:
    print('xml is not well performed')
```